# Space between forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi please see the demo below. I cannot work out how to get rid of the space between the first form?! any help would be appreciated :)

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WYS2g/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix with CSS:

```
#friendlist input {
    float:left;
}
#friendlist {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/WYS2g/16/

Now you don't have to worry about ruining the formatting of your HTML syntax in your editor to accommodate for a browser quirk.

Answer (score 5):

The absolute simplest fix is to remove the whitespace in the HTML.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/WYS2g/10/

```
<input type="text" name="friend_name[]" class="friendid">

    <input type="text" name="friend_email[]" class="friendid"/>
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="friend_name[]" class="friendid"><input type="text" name="friend_email[]" class="friendid"/>
```

Comment: You can't honestly rely on that though. It's the same browser bug as adding a line break after images ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy: If you mean that it's easy for whitespace to "accidentally" get added back, then I agree - you do have to be careful. Otherwise, this is a reliable fix.

Comment: Yea I mean, say dev "A" uses this fix in Textpad, and dev "B" uses Netbeans or any other IDE and has auto-formatting on save enabled. Fix reverted and unless the two devs sit next to each other, dev "B" will be oblivious or possibly have to change his IDE settings to accommodate for the browser quirk :/

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the space between the inputs in the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/WYS2g/8/